# Windows Notifications Service: 401 Invalid Token when trying to create a Toast notification in PHP

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I have been trying to send a Toast notification to a simulator.
I created the Windows Phone 8.1 app and Associated it with the app in the store.
Afterwards I managed to get the access token that I have to use to call the channel URI.

When I try to send a Toast Notification using the channel URI and access token I get this error.

```
Bearer error="invalid_request",error_description="Invalid token"
```

This is the php test code that I created.

```
<?php

    //GET ACCESS TOKEN
    $tokenRequest = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($tokenRequest, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf');

    curl_setopt($tokenRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));

    //FIELDS
    $fields = array(
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => '0',
        'client_secret' => 'Q',
        'scope' => 'notify.windows.com'
    );

    $fields_string = "";
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    curl_setopt($tokenRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($tokenRequest,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($tokenRequest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    $output = json_decode(curl_exec($tokenRequest));
    curl_close($tokenRequest);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($output);
    echo "<br>";
    $accessToken = $output->{'access_token'};


    //SEND PUSH
    $sendPush = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAABuWLaYT1f9BVJwNJCjc243U1OFXUT8MCqvsME%2ftDnhPG%2f%2fJSurxP3u1y47eqmrQZSPUlZH7koHW3Zwdj5938LYZNRdDyE6JzvyHOZvZvSo%3d');

    //TOAST MESSAGE
    $toastMessage = "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
            "<wp:Toast>" .
            "<wp:Text1>" . "SendToast" . "</wp:Text1>" .
            "<wp:Text2>" . "Text Message" . "</wp:Text2>" .
            "</wp:Toast> " .
            "</wp:Notification>"; 

    curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml', "Content-Length: " . strlen($toastMessage), "X-WNS-Type: wns/toast", "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken");
    curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($sendPush,CURLOPT_POST, 1);        
    curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toastMessage);         

    $output = curl_exec($sendPush);

    echo "<br>";
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($sendPush, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($sendPush, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($output);
    curl_close($sendPush);
    // Create request to send
?>
```

In c# I use this to get the channel URI.

```
 channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(channel.Uri);
```

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: The 401 usually means the server has not been authorized or the client secret is wrong. I don't know CURL but you can compare your logic with mine in .NET by following this walkthrough: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/04/walkthrough-creating-an-iis-server-to-use-with-wns-push-notifications-and-windows-store-apps.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution.

The client_id that you have to send to request the token isn't the Client ID of your app.
Instead of sending the Client ID you have to send the Package SID.
Very confusing.

Comment: One more thing to add. You need the *entire* package SID. That includes the protocol "ms-app://".