# WNS push notification cannot be sent

Tags: c#, oauth, uwp, wns

I'm using the following code to send a push raw notification to my app. The code is taken from the examples given in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh868252(v=win.10)).

```
public string PostToWns(string secret, string sid, string uri, string xml, string notificationType, string contentType)
{
    try
    {
        var accessToken = GetAccessToken(secret, sid);

        byte[] contentInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", notificationType);
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken.AccessToken));

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(contentInBytes, 0, contentInBytes.Length);

        using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        //                              ^^^^^ This throws an exception ^^^^^
            return webResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
    }

    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        HttpStatusCode status = ((HttpWebResponse)webException.Response).StatusCode;

        if (status == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            GetAccessToken(secret, sid);
            return PostToWns(uri, xml, secret, sid, notificationType, contentType);
        }
        else if (status == HttpStatusCode.Gone || status == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else if (status == HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            string[] debugOutput = {
                                status.ToString(),
                                webException.Response.Headers["X-WNS-Debug-Trace"],
                                webException.Response.Headers["X-WNS-Error-Description"],
                                webException.Response.Headers["X-WNS-Msg-ID"],
                                webException.Response.Headers["X-WNS-Status"]
                            };
            return string.Join(" | ", debugOutput);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message;
    }
}

// Authorization
[DataContract]
public class OAuthToken
{
    [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
}

private OAuthToken GetOAuthTokenFromJson(string jsonString)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OAuthToken));
        var oAuthToken = (OAuthToken)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return oAuthToken;
    }
}

protected OAuthToken GetAccessToken(string secret, string sid)
{
    var urlEncodedSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(secret);
    var urlEncodedSid = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sid);

    var body = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com",
                                urlEncodedSid,
                                urlEncodedSecret);

    string response;
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        response = client.UploadString("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf", body);
    }
    return GetOAuthTokenFromJson(response);
}
```

The server always returns `Unauthorized`. However, I am able to obtain a token without problems and the channel URL used is obtained as in the [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh868221(v=win.10)).

The entire code executes at once, so I doubt the token expires every time.

I tried using online tools to check if push notifications are working and the same `Unauthorized` error happens there.

Do I have to register for WNS somewhere? My app is already in the Store and I have the ID and password from the Live Services website. I use these as credentials to get the token and the token is obtained every time. I described this as part of a related question: [Proper WNS credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873356/proper-wns-credentials).

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in a different question: [Windows Notifications Service: 401 Invalid Token when trying to create a Toast notification in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251327/windows-notifications-service-401-invalid-token-when-trying-to-create-a-toast-n/27269263#27269263).

The `client_id` must be the full SID (including the protocol prefix) and the `client_secret` the password.